# how to convert QString to char**

Tags: c++, qt, c-strings, qstring

I want to call an external program from my Qt application. This requires me to  prepare some arguments for the external command. This will be just like calling another process from terminal. E.g.:

```
app -w=5 -h=6
```

To test this, I have a simple function like:

```
void doStuff(int argc, char** argv){ /* parse arguments */};
```

I try to prepare a set of arguments like this:

```
QString command;
command.append(QString("-w=%1 -h=%2 -s=%3 ")
               .arg("6").arg("16").arg(0.25));
command.append("-o=test.yml -op -oe");
std::string s = command.toUtf8().toStdString();
char cstr[s.size() + 1];
char* ptr = &cstr[0];

std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), cstr);
cstr[s.size()] = '\0';
```

Then I call that function:

```
doStuff(7, &cstr);
```

But I get the wrong argumetns (corrupted) in the debuggre and my parser (opencv `CommandLineParser` crashes!

[image]

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you could possibly have chosen a better name for your yaml file

Comment: Just use `QProcess::start`. It conveniently takes a `QStringList` for arguments. Note that `-w=6`, `-h=2` and so on should each be a separate argument; they are not supposed to be dumped together into one string.

Comment: @TomTanner sorry it was a bit of raging there :) edited to a better name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`doStuff` is expecting an array of strings not a single string.

Something like this should work:

```
std::vector<std::string> command;
command.push_back(QString("-w=%1").arg("6").toUtf8().toStdString());
command.push_back(QString("-h=%2").arg("16").toUtf8().toStdString());
command.push_back(QString("-s=%3").arg("0.25").toUtf8().toStdString());
command.push_back("-o=test.yml");
command.push_back("-op");
command.push_back("-oe");
std::vector<char*> cstr;
std::transform(command.begin(), command.end(), std::back_inserter(cstr),[](std::string& s){return s.data();});
doStuff(cstr.size(), cstr.data());
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I think at the lat line the argumetns must ebe swapped and anyway I get this error `cannot initialize a parameter of type 'char **' with an rvalue of type ...`   and that type is a huge template name

Comment: @dekker, try now

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just had to add another element at the beginning of the vector as the application name (apparently that is also counted as argument!). And I really need to learn that algorithm magic :))

Answer (score 1):

Because you need to split your space separated string into individual strings for arguments.

argv points to an *array of strings* - what you need to end up with is something like

```
argv[0] -> "-w=6"
argv[1] -> "-h=16"
...
argv[7] -> 0
```

which writing the string over your char array isn't going to achieve, as thats just treating cstr as an array of characters.